# jquery logout function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam using below code before unload to logout the user.
 I have 3 levels of authentication, in second level authentication page i injected this code. If user is 2 factor authentication user, user will stop at the page where i injected the code and if user closes the browser user will be logged out/ session will be terminated.
But if user is passing through 2 level authentication i see pop-up as You are loggedout and user is able to login. what i need is: on close event only pop-up has to come.

I used window.onbeforeunload, window.onunload and all other options, it is not working for some browsers.
Please suggest.

```
var timeoutID;
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function(){    
    logout();
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(displayMessage(),500);
});

function logout() {
    window.location.href = "logout url";
}

function displayMessage(){
    window.alert( "You are loggedout" );
}
```

Comment: You cannot redirect the user on a `beforeunload` event. Send a non-async ajax request to a script that will log out the user instead. Better yet, use session cookies.

Answer (score 0):

```
timeoutID = window.setTimeout(displayMessage(),500);
```

should be:

```
timeoutID = window.setTimeout(displayMessage,500);
```

The first argument to `setTimeout` must be a function. You're calling the function instead of passing the function itself. That's why the alert is popping up.

However, because of the restrictions on what you can do in a `beforeunload` handler, this will still work. This is just meant to show you the correct syntax for creating timeout functions.

Comment: You can't use a timer in beforeunload because the page will be closed before it runs.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks. I updated the answer to make it clear that I'm just helping him understand the correct `setTimeout` syntax, not that it will actually solve his ultimate problem.

Comment: No luck. When i close the window now, it is not showing pop-up. By showing this pop-up i'll have time to terminate session at backend. So for this reason i added setTimeout. Any other alternate solution?

Comment: Did you read jfriend00's answer? What part of "this will not work" did you misunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

Two things you cannot do in beforeunload handlers are:

1. Redirect the user to a different page (not allowed by the browser).
2. Set a timer that will run at some future time (the page will already be closed so there is no future time).

So, neither of the things you're trying to do in your beforeunload handler will work.  (FYI, there are other restrictions in beforeunload too such as you can't use `prompt()` or `alert()`, etc... but these are the two that you were doing).

You don't say how login/logout is tracked so it's hard for us to know exactly what to suggest.  A session cookie will expire automatically when the browser is closed.  A regular cookie can be cleared easily in your beforeunload handler.